# Sobolev space is contained in continuous function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading Applied Analysis written by J. K. Hunter. And Exercise 11.12 is to prove if $s>n/2$, then $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{\text{the space of continuous functions that approach 0 at infinity}\}$, where $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n): \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|k|^2)^s|\hat{f}(k)|^2dk< \infty\}$.

My question is from the definition, $f\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can have some discontinuity. How should I understand the inclusion relationship $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, an element of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (and $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$) is not a function $f$ but an equivalence class $[f]$ which consists of all the functions which are equal to $f$ almost everywhere. In the context of Sobolev spaces, the meaning of "inclusions" such as $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is that one can choose for each equivalence class $[f] \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a (unique) representative $g \in [f]$ which is continuous and vanishes at infinity (and such that $g = f$ almost everywhere).

Even more formally, there is a (unique, continuous, injective) map $i \colon H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $[i([f])] = [f]$ so one can identify $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with its image under this map as a subspace of continuous functions.